# Most efficient way to append rows from one dataframe to another

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data2 = [['Name 1', 20, 20, 15, 20], ['Name 2', 15, 10, 10, 8]]
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2, columns=['Name', 1, 2, 3, 4])

data1 = [['New 1', 5, 10, 15, 20], ['New 2', 2, 5, 10 , 20]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data1, columns=['Name', 1, 2, 3, 4])

print(df)

    Name  1   2   3   4
0  New 1  5  10  15  20
1  New 2  2   5  10  20

new_line = df.iloc[0]
df2 = df2.append(new_line)

print(df2)

     Name   1   2   3   4
0  Name 1  20  20  15  20
1  Name 2  15  10  10   8
0   New 1   5  10  15  20
```

I have the desired result I want. However, when I loop through this hundreds of times increasing the df.iloc[1], [2], etc it seems to bottleneck my for loop. Is there a more efficient way to select a row of df then append it to df2?

Comment: Do you know all the rows you want to select ahead of time?

Comment: Can't you just [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) them?

Comment: Yes, `concat` would be best if you want to append ALL of `df` to `df2`, OP.

Comment: I don't though, I want to append one at a time, then I do some operations on it. Go back to the beginning, append the second row, rinse and repeat a few thousand times. Essentially, I want df2 to always be the same with just one additional line at a time from df.

Comment: What kind of operations? You could potentially still `concat` will all the rows you want at once, and then use a growing slice to perform the operations.

Comment: Would be helpful if you could provide a better example, and perhaps some of the operations you want to use. As your question stands and given the information you've provided, no, there isn't a way to do it more efficiently specifically because you are the one introducing the bottleneck by constraining your operations to occur after every row is added.

Comment: For a bit more clarity, I append row 1 to df2, compare the numbers in df2, remove the row I appended. I append row 2 to df2, compare, remove that row. Each row from df has to be independently compared to df2.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to append the whole dataframe something like this should do the trick:

```
df.append(df2)
```

But I am assuming you know this already, and only want a selected few specified rows. In that case, I would create an array with the desired rowsID's from df2 that you want to append to df.

So something like this should work:

```
rowidarr = []
for items in df.iterrows():
    ###condition to get rowid you want
    rowidarr.append(index)
filter_df  = df[df.index.isin(rowidarr)]
df.append(filter_df)
```